# Вывод базы данных в DataGridView

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь вывести таблицу из БД в DataGridView при этом что бы колонки назывались по другому, не так как в БД

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

var Orders = db.Orders
   .Select(x => new {
     FullName = x.Clients.fullName
   })
   .ToList();

dgvOrders.DataSource = Orders;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что бы вместо FullName отображалось "ФИО"?

Comment: `new { FullName = x.Clients.fullName }` - вот тут можете просто переименовать, всяко это какой то анонимный класс.

Answer (score 1):

Может не совсем понял, что вы хотите, но так:

```
dgvOrders.Columns[0].HeaderText="ФИО";
```

Comment: да, но думаю что можно как-то использовать атрибуты для задания имя столбца?

Comment: буду дома, попробую. А вы не попробовали вариант Monk'a?
`new { ФИО= x.Clients.fullName }`

Comment: В принципе так бы и делал, но если не просто "ФИО", а что то с пробелами "ФИО Клиента"